# the property 'title' was not found on object of type "eventstore"

Tags: xcode, object, ekeventstore

I am following a tutorial on [here](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-event-kit-framework/) which consist of Event management with notifications and all. Now the problem is that i am getting errors in the following Codes

My .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction) NewEvent:(id)sender;


@end
```

My .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction) NewEvent:(id)sender {

    EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEventStore *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

    myEvent.title = @"New Event"; // <-- Errors are appearing hear as shown in the title.


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

**Additional information:**
i have already added the frame work but still getting error as show above in the code. The name of the code is

> the property 'title' was not found on object of type "eventstore"

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't think your code matches up with that error message (which itself doesn't look genuine). Can you (a) copy-paste the error message *directly* from Xcode, rather than paraphrasing it, and (b) double-check that you're actually setting `myEvent.title` instead of `eventDB.title`?

Comment: ok i found my Error solution. I wrote the code wrong. I wrote ` EKEventStore *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];` rather than writing `EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];` So my fault. Can you please answer with this Answer that i gave you so that i can vote up please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to double-check that `myEvent` is the right type (`EKEvent *` rather than `EKEventStore *`) and that you're actually trying to set the title on `myEvent` rather than `eventDB`. The error you posted indicates that you're setting `title` on an event store, instead of just an event.